# Validating JQueryUI Modal Form keeping model Data Annotations

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I'm very new to Javascript and jQuery.

I was following the code proposed in this thread: [Validate JQuery UI modal form within another form in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868980/validate-jquery-ui-modal-form-within-another-form-in-mvc-4) to create a modal form using the Data Annotations validation.

It works fine with the validation, but when I complete the form correctly and try to save the information and close it, it saves, but the dialog doesn't close and stays that way until I refresh the page.

Here is how my form is coded:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId ="editDialog", OnSuccess = "editSucces" }))
{        
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Editar Usuário</legend>

        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdUsuario, new { id = "idUsuario"})
        </div>

        Nome
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { id = "nomeUsuario"})
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
        </div>

        E-mail / Login
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login, new { id = "loginUsuario"})
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
        </div>

        Senha
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { id = "senhaUsuario"})
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "Index")
</div>
 }
```

this is my controller action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Usuario usuario, string confsenha)
{
        if (usuario.Senha == confsenha)
        {
            usuario.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Edit", usuario);
            }
            return View(usuario);

        }
}
```

and this is my javascript call:

```
$(function () {
$('.openDialog').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: { idUsuario: $('#idUsuario').val() },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result').html(result).dialog('open');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$('#result').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false
});
});
function editSucces(result) {
if (result.value) {
    $('#result').dialog('close');        
    window.location.href = '/usuario/index';
} else {
    $('#result').html(result);
}
}
```

Running it, I saw that it never enters this part of the javascript code:

```
if (result.value) {
    $('#result').dialog('close');        
    window.location.href = '/usuario/index';
}
```

so, it never goes to the part where it should close the dialog. Does anyone know why this is happening? Or what should be passing in the `result.value` ?

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Just had to return a Json value to the if `(result.value)`. Very simple  though I had to sleep on it to get it >.<

Here is the code after fixing:

Controller:

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return Json(new { cadastro = true });
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
```

Javascript:

```
function editSucces(result) {
    if (result.cadastro) {
        $('#result').dialog('close');        
        window.location.href = '/usuario/index';
    } else{
        $('#result').html(result);
    }
```

}